# How to calculate quarterly returns from monthly?

Tags: rate-of-return

The following monthly returns:

```
56.12%
15.00%
-2.27
```

equal `75.46%` for the quarter.

What is the calculation to get `75.46%`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The calculation is *product*.

Given monthly returns X%, Y%, Z%, quarterly return Q% is calculated as:

`Q% = ((1 + X%/100) * (1 + Y%/100) * (1 + Z%/100) - 1) * 100%`

Using the numbers from the question:

`Q% = ((1 + 56.12/100) * (1 + 15.00/100) * (1 - 2.27/100) - 1) * 100% =`

`= (1.5612 * 1.15 * 0.9773 - 1) * 100% = 75.46%`

Comment: Is the last product of 100% needed since it is just multiplying by 1?

Comment: @4thSpace All those `/100` and `*100` are unnecessary. They're there just to make unit conversion explicit. 50% already equals 0.5 without them.

Comment: Is there a name for this type of calculation?